# Error when applying trimws() inside a for-loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, encoding, subscript

I am trying to apply `trimws()` function for every row of every column of every df contained in a list of df's in R.

Here's my code:

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
  for (j in i) {
    for(z in j){
      df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]] <- 
        trimws(df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]])
    }
    
  }  
  
}
```

Console output:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

Is there any other way to apply this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could make it simpler by looping over the `list` with `lapply` and then applying the `trimws` columnwise with `lapply` (as `trimws` is vectorized)

```
df_list1 <- lapply(df_list, function(dat) {
                 dat[] <- lapply(dat, trimws)
                dat
         })
```

---

By doing the `j in i` and `z in j`, it is assuming that the `length` of the `list` is the same as the number of columns and number of rows of each of the dataset, which may not be the case and thus result in subscript out of bounds error.

Based on the below example data, the `length` is 10, but `nrow` and `ncol` is less than that, which results in the subscript error

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
   for (j in i) {
     for(z in j){
       df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]] <- 
         trimws(df_list[[i]][[j]][[z]])
     }
     
   }  
   
 }
```

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

#### data

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(col1 = c("a ", "b", "c "), col2 = c("b ", 
"d", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    col1 = c("a ", "b", "c ", "d"), col2 = c("b ", "d", "f", 
    "g "), col3 = c(" f", "d", "m ", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(col1 = c("a ", "b", "c "), col2 = c("b ", 
"d", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    col1 = c("a ", "b", "c ", "d"), col2 = c("b ", "d", "f", 
    "g "), col3 = c(" f", "d", "m ", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(col1 = c("a ", "b", "c "), col2 = c("b ", 
"d", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    col1 = c("a ", "b", "c ", "d"), col2 = c("b ", "d", "f", 
    "g "), col3 = c(" f", "d", "m ", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(col1 = c("a ", "b", "c "), col2 = c("b ", 
"d", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    col1 = c("a ", "b", "c ", "d"), col2 = c("b ", "d", "f", 
    "g "), col3 = c(" f", "d", "m ", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)), structure(list(col1 = c("a ", "b", "c "), col2 = c("b ", 
"d", "f")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    col1 = c("a ", "b", "c ", "d"), col2 = c("b ", "d", "f", 
    "g "), col3 = c(" f", "d", "m ", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

Comment: since `trimws` is vectorized then `lapply(df_list, function(dat) {dat[]<-trimws(as.matrix(dat)); dat})` should do the trick. No need of the second lapply

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, that is possible, but if there are class differences, it may have some issues